# Can't get messages using NEventStore polling example

Tags: neventstore

I'm a newbie with NEventStore project and I'm trying to run it's examples in order to analyze if it fits with our project's needs.

I'm having trouble with the Polling example, it's throwing an error while serializing an existing commit in my SQL DB.

I first used the NEventStore.Example to register some events and they appeared in my SQL DB without trouble, but when I try to retrieve those messages using the other sample called NEventStore.PollingClientExample I'm getting the following json error.

*Error resolving type specified in JSON 'NEventStore.Example.SomeDomainEvent, NEventStore.Example'.*

Has anybody tried those samples? Do they work together?

Comment: Second this, you found a solution for it?